# Wordpress wp_insert_user( ) stops while loop // Create Users in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I need to import / create User with some .csv files.
For this I´m using the function `wp_insert_user( )` inside a `while` loop through the CSV until it returns `FALSE` like this:

```
 if (($handle = fopen($folder.$storagename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $user_name = $data[0]; // Kundennummer
        $password = $data[1]; // PLZ
        $user_nicename = $data[2]; // Angebotsnummer
        $user_email = 'system-user-'.rand().
                      '@xy.de'; // User Email
        $args = array(
            'user_login' => $user_name,
            'user_pass' => $password,
            'user_email' => $user_email,
            'user_nicename' => $user_nicename,
            'display_name' => $password
        );
        wp_insert_user($args);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo "All in.";
```

But the loop stops when it loops for the second time.
I think there is some problem with `wp_insert_user( )` itself because if i comment it out the loop runs through all entries...

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure WordPress is loaded when you're doing this? If not, the `wp_insert_user` function doesn't exist...

Comment: It must be loaded because:

It loops 2 times and 2 Users will be created and are visible in Wordpress Backend.... but then it stops an no more User will be managed / created.

Comment: Okay I made a step forward!

I think the script itself is okay - just tested my Plugin on another Server / Wordpress Installation - there it runs through!

Some Idea which Server Configuration could be wrong?